# Removal of items in minecraft spigot plugin

Tags: instance, bukkit

So I'm trying to make a mushroom stew that when you drink it, it gives you back 6 food, but when I tried to remove the stew via `remove(Material.MUSHROOM_STEW);` I realised it can remove all the stew you have in your inventory when you drink it. May I know how to remove 1 item only when you drink it? For the code just label the food meter going up as `// do stuff`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this. On the *PlayerItemConsumeEvent* we check what item the player ate.
Then if it's a stew, we cancel the eating event then we give the player 6 extra food levels and remove the item from their inventory.

```java
@EventHandler
public void PlayerItemConsumeEvent(PlayerItemConsumeEvent e) {
    if(e.getItem().equals(new ItemStack(Material.MUSHROOM_STEW))) {
        // player ate stew
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        e.setCancelled(true);
        player.setFoodLevel(player.getFoodLevel() + 6);
        player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().setAmount(player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getAmount() - 1);
        return;
    }
    // player ate something else than stew
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are a new contributor. I would go back home and try it out and come back to you, I'm in school right now... I think it makes sense so far

Comment: uhh when the food level doesnt seem to go up by what i set it to because i set it to 10

Comment: There are twenty food levels, if you make it go up by ten it adds five hunger bars.

Comment: You should always check for the item in hand to be non-null. Sometimes it will be even though the player is suppose to have a soup in his hand. Also, there are 20 food slots by default (+6 food slots = 12 food halfs). You might also want to cap the food level with `Math.max(player.getFoodLevel() + 12, 20);`

Comment: BorisNL I know but it still increases by only 6, I want to make custom soup that when you drink it, it gives you 10 hunger points

Comment: frederic perron why would it ever return null?